# Lighting artifacts on plane in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, artifacts

I have a plane with an image projected on it:

[image: Screenshot 1]

But in the rendering and viewport, there are these stroboscopic lines that are especially noticeable in animations:

[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

I tried playing around with the shader and the number of samples, but it didn't help.

[image: Screenshot 4]

Did anyone face this problem, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your plane is lit and has some roughness. This can create glitches/reflections/interactions. It is sometimes better to use the Emission property of the principled BSDF shader (or directly an Emission shader) when the image is supposed to act as a background.

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is that I need to cast shadows and light on these planes, so I'm afraid it can't be done with Emission shader, right?

Comment: In that case, crank up the Roughness to 1 and decrease the Specularity to zero. That should help by avoiding reflections as much as possible.

Comment: Addendum : in Blender version 4.0+, IOR should be also decreased to 1.0 in addition to Roughness to 1.0 and Specular to 0.0 to prevent any reflection.